# 'Gallery slider' how do you create a thumbnail image marker that corresponds with the gallery image on click using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, slider, gallery

Hi I'm trying to create a gallery slider using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3. At the moment I have my slider working ("id="container") and I also have a list of colour thumbnails ("id="colour") that I click on to change the main image in the slider.

What I'm trying to work out is how to highlight the colour thumbnails by overlaying/swapping individual B&W images from a separate table (id="B&W")? I want these B&W images to appear one at a time and act as marker letting the user know how far they've scrolled along in the gallery slider?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html lang="en">
    <head> <script src="js/browser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <title>image slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="container">
                <img src="img1.png" id="img" alt="image_gallery"/>

                <div id="left_holder">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onClick=" slider(-1)" class="left"/>Left arrow</a>
                </div>

                <div id="right_holder"> 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img onClick="slider(1)" class="right"/>Right arrow</a>
                </div>
                <div id="description"> 1.description.... </div>
        </div>



    <table id="Table_01" >
        <tr id="B&W">
        <!--Individual B&W thumbnails should appear and disappear to correspond with larger "container" img above and 'c_thumbnails' below-->
            <td>
                <img id="B&W_thumbnails_1" src="B&W_thumbnails_1.jpg" width="18" height="80" alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <img id="B&W_thumbnails_2" src="B&W_thumbnails_2.jpg" width="49" height="80" alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <img id="B&W_thumbnails_3" src="B&W_thumbnails_3.jpg" width="56" height="80" alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <img id="B&W_thumbnails_4" src="B&W_thumbnails_4.jpg" width="48" height="80" alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <img id="B&W_thumbnails_5" src="B&W_thumbnails_5.jpg" width="44" height="80" alt="" /></td>

        </tr>


    <tr id="colour">
        <!--Each 'onClick' changes the "container" img to a corresponding larger image-->
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(0)"><img id="c_thumbnails_1" src="c_thumbnails_1.jpg" width="18" height="80" alt=""/></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(0)"><img id="c_thumbnails_2" src="c_thumbnails_2.jpg" width="49" height="80" alt=""/></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(1)"><img id="c_thumbnails_3" src="c_thumbnails_3.jpg" width="56" height="80" alt=""/></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(2)"><img id="c_thumbnails_4" src="c_thumbnails_4.jpg" width="48" height="80" alt=""/></a></td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="thumbnail(3)"><img id="c_thumbnails_5" src="c_thumbnails_5.jpg" width="44" height="80" alt=""/></a></td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also in JavaScript the B&W thumbnail marker needs to be linked to both the Gallery slider function "slider(num)" and the colour thumbnails function "thumbnail(x)".

```
        var Image = ["img1.png", "img2.png","img3.png","img4.png"];
        var Description = ["1.description....", "2.description....","3.description....","4.description...."];
        var B&W = ["B&W_thumbnails_1.jpg","B&W_thumbnails_2.jpg","B&W_thumbnails_3.jpg","B&W_thumbnails_4.jpg"];
        var Image_Number = 0;
        var Image_Length = Image.length -1;

    function slider(num){
            var Images = document.getElementById('img');
            Image_Number = Image_Number + num;

            if (Image_Number > Image_Length){
                Image_Number = 0;       
            }

            if (Image_Number < 0){
                Image_Number = Image_Length;
            }

            Images.src=Image[Image_Number];
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = Description[Image_Number];
            return false;
            }

    //what will make the individual B&W_thumbnail jpegs appear/disappear in correspondence with both the slider and thumbnail function?
    //function ?B&W_thumbnails(x){}

    function thumbnail(x){
            var Images = document.getElementById('img');
            Image_Number = Image_Number + x;
            Images.src=Image[x];
            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = Description[x];
            }
```

In the future I want to add more images to this gallery slider so I was hoping there was a really simple way in JavaScript to change the position of the thumbnails.

Comment: I don't see any questions here...

Comment: Second line of the second paragraph at the top

Comment: still don't see it...

Comment: I've changed the heading into the question you just have to read on